# Static code analysis to find references to "self" within blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, code-analysis

One of the most common bugs I find is when I have referenced "self" in a block like this:

```
 ...
 [self someMethodWhichTakesBlock:^() {
       self.something = @"something";
 }];
 ...
```

What I SHOULD be writing is something more like this:

```
 ...
 __block MyObject *_self = self;
 [self someMethodWhichTakesBlock:^() {
       _self.something = @"something";
 }];
 ...
```

Is there any way to catch these potential bugs with a static code analysis of some sort?

Comment: Is it not caught if you run [Clang](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html)?

Comment: I noticed that Xcode 4.6 will warn you for this in the static analyzer

Comment: Note that the above is only an error if the block is then stored in an ivar. If it is immediately executed and discarded, there is no retain loop here.

Comment: Rob - yes...it's just at this point, I have encountered so many situations where the blocks are initially executed immediately, but then weeks later the method implementation stores the blocks somewhere to be called later...so I'd rather always err on the side of caution instead of having strange crashes later on down the road.

Comment: "What I SHOULD be writing is something more like this:" Only in MRC. In ARC, you need to use `__unsafe_unretained` or `__weak`.